# Error connection with JDBC to Oracle service name (jaydebeapi)

Tags: java, python, oracle, raspberry-pi3, jaydebeapi

I try to make Oracle request in python from Raspberry pi. The problem is:

"Oracle does not support the ARM CPU architecture which the Raspberry Pi uses. You downloaded and unzipped the Oracle Instant Client, but it can't actually run. And without the Oracle Client libraries, cx_oracle will not work, and neither will generic Python ODBC connectors."

But I need python, so installed JPype and JayDeBeApi and I wrote this on jupyter notebopok:

```py
import jaydebeapi
import jpype
from jpype import *
```

```py
classpath="ava-1.5.0-gcj-6-armhf"
```

```py
jvm_path = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-6-armhf/lib"
```

```py
jHome = jpype.getDefaultJVMPath()
```

```py
print(jHome)
```

/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/jre/lib/arm/client/libjvm.so

```py
conn=jaydebeapi.connect('oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver','[admin]/[root]@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=helloworld.com)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=hello42)))')
```

but I have this error:

```py
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-82d7959b353e> in <module>
----> 1 conn=jaydebeapi.connect('oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver','[admin]/[root]@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=helloworld.com)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=hello42)))')

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/jaydebeapi/__init__.py in connect(jclassname, url, driver_args, jars, libs)
    379     else:
    380         libs = []
--> 381     jconn = _jdbc_connect(jclassname, url, driver_args, jars, libs)
    382     return Connection(jconn, _converters)
    383 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/jaydebeapi/__init__.py in _jdbc_connect_jpype(jclassname, url, driver_args, jars, libs)
    181         types_map = {}
    182         for i in types.__javaclass__.getClassFields():
--> 183             types_map[i.getName()] = i.getStaticAttribute()
    184         _init_types(types_map)
    185     global _java_array_byte

AttributeError: '_jpype.PyJPField' object has no attribute 'getStaticAttribute'
```

how to fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What JPype version do you use? There was a new version released last week. If you are using version 0.7.0 try the previous version 0.6.3

Comment: I check this with: pip3 install jpype1: 
"Requirement already satisfied: jpype1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (0.7.0)"

Comment: try this: `pip3 install JPype1==0.6.3`

Comment: I'm glad that I could help you. Mark my answer please as the solution. Thank you :)

Comment: @Erik, take an upvote my good friend.  Thanks for pointing this out.  I've been battling the same issue this morning.  I also note that there is a current open issue for this on Github.